# Android studio 1.3 NDK cannot resolve c++ header / code

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm quite new using Android Studio 1.3.2 and even more using the NDK.
I'm trying to using OpenCV 2.4.11 and C++.
I'm using Gradle 2.6.

So far and oddly OpenCV doesn't generate any errors in the C++ code. Just When I'm including C++ headers like  or , it cannot resolve them. Same goes for Try...Catch that are unresolved.
Again, I started using Android Studio like 2 weeks ago and NDK 1 week ago. I'm still not sure what I'm doing.

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_face_rt_facert_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_10(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                         jclass type) {

try {
    cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> pfr = cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    pfr.addref(); // this is for the 2.4 branch, 3.0 would need a different treatment here
    return (jlong) pfr.obj;
     } catch (...) {
    jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
    env->ThrowNew(je, "sorry, dave..");
    }
    return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My build.gradle file for the project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "face.rt.facert"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.1"
    }

}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
    }
}

android.ndk { // keeping it to make AS correctly support C++ code editing and debugging
    moduleName = "Face"
    ldLibs += ['log']
    cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
    cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/prebuilts/include")}".toString()
    cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()
    cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString()
    cppFlags  += "-I${file("C:/Android-dev/SDKs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2")}".toString()
    stl = "gnustl_shared" //"stlport_static"
}


android.productFlavors {
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    create("arm") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters += "armeabi"

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\" //"-L" +

            ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

        }
    }
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath+"\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\" //"-L" +

            ldLibs += libsDir + "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_contrib.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_core.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_info.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java.so"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_legacy.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a"
            ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a"

        }
    }
    create("x86") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters += "x86"
        }
    }
    create("mips") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters += "mips"
        }
    }
    create("fat") {

    }

    // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
    create("all")
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```

And this is my dependencies in my project:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha3'
```

EDIT:

Removed Try...Catch from the function for testing purpose.
Oddly, vector and string headers are now resolved and working.

But now I'm getting few errors about OpenCV at the compile time.

> Error:(16) undefined reference to `cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(int, double)'
>
> Error:(2607) undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkArm64-v8aDebugAllFaceSharedLibrary'.
>   A build operation failed.
>         Linker failed while linking libFace.so.

Comment: If you get errors (of any kind) please include them in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

I found in my build.gradle:

```
    // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
    create("all")
```

all means 32 and 64 bits.
Since my libs are only 32 bits, compiler didn't find the 64bits version and failed.

I removed this line and it works better (Still have some errors but not compiling errors)